# Yubikey with S/MIME certificate

Tags: smime, yubikey

I would like to do the following. Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

1. Store the private key for an S/MIME certificate from Digicert on a Yubikey.
2. Backup the private key to another location.
3. Use my S/MIME certificate to digitally sign and decrypt emails using Outlook 2013 on Windows 10.

Thanks,
Ely

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Store the private key for an S/MIME certificate from Digicert on a Yubikey.

You need to download Yubikey PIV Manager https://developers.yubico.com/yubikey-piv-manager/ that allows storing the certificate to Yubikey.

A nice walktrough for some email clients (but not for Outlook): https://blog.ligos.net/2017-01-02/Smime-Email-and-Yubikey.html